# Java change listBox items color

Tags: java, list, listbox

i try to change color of some items in a listBox of my java project.

my code:

```
private ArrayListModel listModelMembers = new ArrayListModel();
private ListBox listMembers;

memberList = app.members.getMembers(handle);

for (Member m : memberList) {
    String display = m.getName();
    listModelMembers.addItem(display, m);
}
listMembers.removeAll();
listMembers.setSelectedIndex(0);
listMembers.setModel(listModelMembers);
Font font = new Font(null, Font.ITALIC, new Extent(9, Extent.PT));
Integer i = 0;
for(DirectoryMember m: memberList){
    if(m.getType() == 2){
        listMembers.setSelectedIndex(i);
        listMembers.setForeground(Color.LIGHTGRAY);
        listMembers.setFont(font);
    }
    i++;
}
listModelMembers.fire();
listMembers.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_SELECTION);
```

But my code change the color of all items, not those i want.
How to set the good indexed element?

Comment: You should be looking for how to use Custom Renderer. Thats the solution to these kind of problems.

Comment: nextapp.echo.app.ListBox;
it's a class of Echo Studio 3

Comment: i tried with a custom renderer, but impossible to handle it, with this method, at least, i can change the font..